# On Error GoTo Displays When No Error (for Select Case)

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I've created an excel with several macros and this particular section is really stumping me because it was working perfectly 24 hours ago and I've made no changes to it.

I have a form (Access) that pops up every time someone opens the Excel, and they have to enter their last name, then the sheet that is their name and another sheet called 'Stats' will be visible to them. Everything else hidden. Now if someone puts in 'NOI' it's the 'master password' if you will and almost everything displays.

If they don't capitalize their inputs correctly or misspell something it SHOULD kick out an error message. However, the form is kicking out the error message even when the inputs aren't errors. The correct sheets will display but the error message box comes up no matter what you input. I know there has to be a better way than 'Error GoTo' but I'm not as skilled at using 'Try...'

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim pword As String
    On Error GoTo endit
          pword = TextBox1
          Select Case pword
          Case Is = "NOI": Call UnHideAllSheets
          Case Is <> "NOI": Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Visible = True
    End Select
    Sheets("ERROR").Visible = False
    Sheets("Stats").Visible = True
    Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Activate
    Me.Hide
    Exit Sub
    endit: MsgBox "Incorrect Input: check spelling and capitalization"
End Sub
```

I did not set absolute passwords with individual 'Case Is =' because this is designed to work for people who have absolutely no idea how to make any updates or changes to VBA. All of the people who will be using and updating this don't know the developer tab in excel exists.

Here is the code that the Case Is refers to when it says `Call UnHideAllSheets`:

```
Sub UnHideAllSheets()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim n As Single
    For n = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(n).Visible = True
    Next n

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Sheets("CleanData").Visible = False
    Sheets("Template").Visible = True
    Sheets("ERROR").Visible = False
    Sheets("2018").Activate
End Sub
```

All of this is code I've modified from other locations. Like I said, it was working perfectly 24 hours ago. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: pword = TextBox1     ->       pword = TextBox1.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need a `Select` statement for this a simple `If … Else` would do it.
2. Always deactivate your error handler after the line where you expect the error. Otherwise any error that occurs later will also trigger that error handler and you might get a misleading error message.

So we come up with something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim pword As String
    pword = TextBox1.Value

    If pword = "NOI" Then
        UnHideAllSheets
    Else
        On Error GoTo endit
        Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Visible = True
        On Error GoTo 0 'always deactivate error handler after the expected error
    End If

    Sheets("ERROR").Visible = False
    Sheets("Stats").Visible = True
    Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Activate
    Me.Hide

    Exit Sub
endit: 
    MsgBox "Incorrect Input: check spelling and capitalization"
End Sub
```

Comment: (is your screen name Russian for Ren? Not that it matters :) ) Worked perfectly thank you!
@RicardoA, this didn't work when I input 'NOI' because Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Activate would be trying to activate Sheets("NOI").Activate, which does not exist. But thank you!!